# how to update collision detection rectangles when using canvas.translate

Tags: android, canvas

I created a rectangle using x and y integers which change values when I touch the rectangle and swipe in a certain direction (x increases when I swipe right, y increases when I swipe up, etc.). This rectangle is also being rendered onto a canvas. I have a game loop which calls an update() method and render() method. The update() method updates the x and y values and creates a collision detection rectangle, the render() method then uses these values to render an updated rectangle to my canvas.

Say I use the method canvas.translate(0, -50) before I draw this rectangle in my game loop. The rectangle appears 50 pixels above where it used to be, however my x and y values remain the same so I have to swipe below my rendered rectangle for it to actually do something. What's a simple and efficient way of updating the x and y so that my rectangle is actually located where it is rendered and not below it? I need the collision detection box to be located where the rectangle is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I taught myself how to program, so I am not really sure if there is an easier way, but if I were you whenever you call canvas.translate() just change the x and y values to adjust. For example, this is what I would do for the sample you gave:

```
    canvas.translate(0, -50)
    x = x+0
    y = y+(-50)
```

If you are too lazy to add the extra two lines you could put it all in to a function and just replace canvas.translate() with whatever function you made.

In fact I will make that function right now. Why not?

```
    public void translate(double XMove, double YMove) {
         canvas.translate(XMove, YMove);
         x = x+XMove;
         y = y+YMove;
    }
```

Comment: I intend on making it be translate(player.getX, player.getY) where player will be the square I swipe. So this method will be in my game loop and will get called repeatably. So while the player is standing still, the method will keep getting called and will keep adding to x and y making them off the map. If I do it with the above example translate(0, -50) then y will approach negative infinity rather then my intended y.

Comment: I was just giving an example based on your "Say I use the method canvas.translate(0, -50)". You will have to calculate the change yourself, or post another question. I gave a function that will translate any coordinate step, so you will have to calculate the move then pass that on to the function.